# (Java) Cannot Find Symbol for method

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

I'm having trouble with some binary tree stuff, specifically, I can't get a method defined in the original class to work in another.

```
public class BTNode<E>
{// Invariant of the BTNode<E> class:
   //   1. Each node has one reference to an E Object, stored in the instance
   //      variable data.
   //   2. The instance variables left and right are references to the node's
   //      left and right children.
   private E data;
   private BTNode<E> left, right;   

   public BTNode(E initialData, BTNode<E> initialLeft, BTNode<E> initialRight)
   {
      data = initialData;
      left = initialLeft;
      right = initialRight;
   }       


   public E getData( )   
   {
      return data;
   }
```

Why am I unable to use the getData(),getLeft(), getRight() methods in another class? for example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class BinSearchTree {

  private BTNode<Pair<Integer,String>> root;

  public BinSearchTree() { 
    root = null;
  }

  public BinSearchTree(BTNode<Pair<Integer,String>> aNode){
     this.root = aNode; 
  }

  public BinSearchTree(Pair<Integer,String> aPair) { 
    this.root = new BTNode<Pair<Integer,String>>(aPair,null, null);
  }

  public boolean insert(Pair<Integer,String> aPair){  
    Integer key = aPair.getX();
    if (this.getData( ).getX() == key){return false;}
    if (this.getData().getX()<key){
      if (this.getLeft()== null){this.setLeft(BTNode(aPair, null, null));}
      else{this.getLeft().insert(aPair);}}
    else{
      if (this.getRight()== null){this.setRight(BTNode(aPair, null, null));}
      else{this.getRight().insert(aPair);}}

    return true; 
  }
```

The use of getData in the insert function is causing a "cannot find symbol" error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `this` refers to the current class you are in. You are using `this` inside `BinSearchTree` where there is no function defined called `getData()`

You should use `root.getData()` instead since `root` is an instance of the class `BTNode` therefore it has the function `getData()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `this.getData()` you need `root.getData()`, same with `this.getLeft()` (`root.getLeft()`) and `this.getRight()` (`root.getRight()`).